# Finite Model Property of Epistemic Logics

Tags: logic, modal-logic, decidability

I'm working through Fagin *et al.*'s *Reasoning About Knowledge* and got stuck in their proof of the decidability of the epistemic logic $K_n$ (characterized by the class of all Kripke frames for $n$ agents $(W, R_1, \ldots, R_n)$, where every $R_i$ is a 2-place relation on $W$).

As usual in their presentation Fagin *et al.* derive decidability from the fact that $K_n$ has the finite model property, which they express in their theorem 3.2.2 (p. 64f.) (here $M^n$ denotes the class of all Kripke models for $n$ agents, $|\varphi|$ is the length of formula $\varphi$):

> If $\varphi$ is satisfiable in some model from $M^n$, then $\varphi$ is satisfiable in some finite model from $M^n$ whose carrier contains at most $2^{|\varphi|}$ points.

The proof is straightforward with the exception of a single step. Let $con(\varphi)$ be the set of all maximally consistent subsets of $sub(\varphi) \cup \lbrace \neg \psi:\psi \in sub(\varphi)\rbrace$, where $sub(\varphi)$ is the set of subformulas of $\varphi$. The problematic step goes as follows:

Clearly, every member of $con(\varphi)$ contains exactly one of $\psi, \neg \psi$ for every $\psi \in sub(\varphi)$. From this the authors conclude that the cardinality of $con(\varphi)$ is at most $2^{|sub(\varphi)|}$, where $|sub(\varphi)|$ is the cardinality of $sub(\varphi)$.

I cannot see how the reasoning goes here. Obviously the way to go is to find an injection from $con(\varphi)$ to $sub(\varphi)$'s power set. But several attempts of mine to construct one lead nowhere. So how is the required injective function to be constructed? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it simply the case that there are $2^n$ distinct ways to make $n$ binary choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fabio has pointed out, an element of $con(\varphi)$ can either contain $\psi$ or $\lnot \psi$, where $\psi \in Sub(\varphi)$. Hence there may be up to $2^{|Sub(\varphi)|}$ ways to pick a set of $\psi$'s from $Sub(\varphi)$.